# Create metadata table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have 5 tables in Source.Each table have PK_ID.I have to populate into destination.I populated the table into destination but 
I want to make a metadata_table in SSIS.The schema of metadata_table -
2 columns- a) table name b) last PK_ID of that table.

in table name column all the 5 table's name should be there and in PK_ID column , last PK_ID of respective table.

How can I do in SSIS. Please help

EDIT:

I need to update the destination table by populating newly inserted data in source table only by comparing PK_Id of source table with the Pk_Id of metatable as shown below
if(Pk_id(Source_table)>Pk_id(Meta_table))
then insert in Destination table(only those records having Pk_id greater than PK_id of metatable) and Update the metatable too by inserting Max(PK_id) of source table.

Comment: There is no data in your meta table. ETL runs. Meta table now has 5 rows with last PK_ID from each source table. ETL runs again. Now what - are there 10 rows or did you update the existing 5?

Comment: Hi Billinkc thanks for your reply.
My problem is how to create a job in ssis to achieve this.I haven't create any job in ssis for this case.I want to know how to create for this particular case.Btw sorry for confusion.Now i can guess,it's clear to you now.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Dataflow for this. I would add 5 OLE DB Source objects, each would return the MAX (PK_ID) (assuming that meets the requirement - "last" is ambigous).

They would also each include a dummy join column e.g.

`SELECT 
1 AS DUMMY_KEY
, MAX ( PK_ID) AS PK_ID1
FROM TABLE1`

Then I would add 4 Merge Join transformations.  Each would join a pair of the OLE DB Source objects, using the DUMMY_KEY as the join.

The result would be a single row with the 5 "last PK_ID" columns.

Comment: Hi Mike
Please go through the edited question and help me out how to achieve this.

Comment: To compare to data from another table, I would add a Lookup and then a Derived Column for simple logic.  To filter the destination table I would use a Conditional Split.